# db.setProfilingLevel(1, 10000) return error: "profile currently not supported via mongos"

Tags: mongodb

I use mongo v2.2.1.
My mongod are running by three sharding.
I want to profile and find my slow queries. So, I use setProfilingLevel(1, 10000) on mongos.

```
$ mongos
  mongos> db.setProfilingLevel(1, 10000);
  { "ok" : 0, "errmsg" : "profile currently not supported via mongos" }
```

Why the error is occurred? and please teach me how to enable profile.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Collection **system.profile** is not sharded, this is why you have to manually enable profiling on each of your shards(not from `mongos`). You also won't be able to query **system.profile** though `mongos`, you'll have to use `mongo` shell on each shard.

**UPD** I found interesting post on [this topic](http://emptysqua.re/blog/real-time-profiling-a-mongodb-cluster/). You should try this solution.

Comment: thanks so much for your tips. I can access mongo shell using "--host 127.0.0.1:27018.